# Difference between MySQL's LIMIT and Teradata's TOP when conditioning on non-indexed variables

Tags: mysql, limit, teradata

Today at work, I tried executing the following command in Teradata and failed:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tab WHERE col <> 1
```

As a coworker explained to me later, Teradata first runs the `WHERE` condition on the entire table (way too big), before selecting `TOP 10`.  According to my coworker, things would be different if `col` was indexed.

Now I wonder if MySQL is actually doing the same; potentially I just never pushed the boundaries enough.  Does

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col != 1 LIMIT 10
```

also run the `col != 1` condition on the entire table before returning the first 10 (let `col` not be indexed if this changes the answer)?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Your colleague is probably wrong about Teradata.

Comment: The query didn't run and gave me spool space errors.  I was only successful when creating a `VOLATILE TABLE` with the `TOP 100` entries (without `WHERE`) first, and then running the `TOP 10 ... WHERE` statement ...

Comment: @GordonLinoff the colleague is completely right about teradata, the top clause is executed after the where. Teradata will first fetch all matching rows into spool, then take the first 10 records. The reason for this is that teradata stores the data belonging to a single table distributed along multiple amps.

Comment: @Shadow . . . Teradata stores the complete data before releasing any of it downstream?

Comment: @GordonLinoff in certain scenarios, yes, thst's what it does. It works completely differently than an average rdbms.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Teradata always creates the **full** answer set before sending it to the client, the **exact** number of rows is returned before the 1st row. This is totally different from any other DBMS I worked with and you get used to this very fast (of course sometimes it would be nice to be able to switch it off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should not use `LIMIT / TOP` unless you also use `ORDER BY`, if you are interested in what exactly is returned (other than the fact there are so many records at all).

Having said that, MySQL will **not** scan the whole table (if `tab` is a table) or index prior to returning the `LIMIT` records: it will return the records as it scans and filters them, and will stop as soon as there are enough of them.

However, if `tab` is not a table, but a view, and if it contains a nested query, or a `GROUP BY` condition or something like that, MySQL might need to scan all the underlying tables prior to filtering and limiting indeed.

Comment: Thank you + fair point on `LIMIT / TOP`.  I mainly use it to just get a "sense for a table";  looking at some entries.  (I understand that these rows are not randomly drawn.)

Comment: Also, if you use `ORDER BY` and it can't determine the order using an index, it will need to scan the entire table.

Answer (score 3):

Things work different on a massive parallel DBMS like Teradata. One system might consist of hundreds of physical servers and thousands of AMPs (Teradata "instances") and a table is distributed amongst all AMPs in a system as @Shadow already mentioned in a comment.

Now when you submit a `TOP` with any `WHERE`-condition (or a join or aggregate) the system will actually create an intermediate spool first with all filtered rows and then apply the top logic. You can easily see that when you `EXPLAIN` the query, the last step includes a *STAT FUNCTION ... used to retrieve the TOP 10 rows*.

You probably did that to have a quick look at the data, so you can remove the `WHERE`-conditon and then it's really fast, because a single AMP will simply read its first datablock(s). If you really need the filtered data you might use this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT TOP 1000 *  
   FROM tab 
 ) AS dt
WHERE col <> 1
```

Use a `TOP n` in the Derived Table which is big enough to return at least 10 rows matching the outer condition.

Comment: Would things be different if `col` was indexed, or would it still create an intermediate spool first with _all_ filtered rows?

Comment: @dotwin: If the index is selective enough the optimizer might use the index to access the rows, but it will still move *all* matching row to the spool first. In Explain there's first a step indicating the index access *by way of index # n* and then the *STAT FUNCTION*.